# Why am I getting this error trying to initialize angular-translate?

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I've included the angular-translate.min into my app, and i know it's finding it because i'm not getting a 404 error.  But when I try and use it, I'm getting an error and I don't know why, any ideas? I figured I'd be able to just include the .js file and start using it. Thanks

`https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=UserAdminApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.20%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DngTranslate%26p1%3DEr`

`https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ngTranslate&p1=Er`

Comment: Are you using this project: http://angular-translate.github.io/ ?

Answer (score 2):

After you load the JavaScript, you still have to inject the module. Depending on how it's set up in your app, it should be something like:

```
var modules = ['pascalprecht.translate'];
var appModule = angular.module('myApp', modules);

appModule.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
  // configure translation here
}]);
```

src: [Angular-Translate docs](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide)